# Post Raw JSON Binary to API Gateway, Lambda and S3

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-api-gateway

Basically I want to drag and drop images onto a web page and then click upload and it will point to an end-point on the API Gateway and pass my binary string up and send to a Lambda Function and process binary string and send to S3.

Anyone done this before? npm packages, tutorials to follow?

Spent about a day on it so far and feel like I'm going around in circles.

Thanks!!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: "JSON binary" is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @BMW Created a Lambda function to take in a base64 string that then takes this and preps for putObject to S3 and using API Gateway for an endpoint taking in a body template. I tested using PostMan with a Post Request, and sent a Raw application/json type with object of binary string, e.g. {base64string: "some value"}

I'm probably missing a few things to get it working properly.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You are right :)

Comment: API Gateway is supporting binary payload to base64 String payload in the request to Lambda function. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html

Comment: @KaHouIeong Yah I did read about this, I probably just need to follow some of their examples and work from there.